# Delete Object in Restkit .20 did not take JSON Values

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6, restkit-0.20

I have an API which is used to delete a record in server database. I used to construct the API with the request ID .It was working with CURL, but in Restkit it seems to give an error.
The Curl is:

> `curl -d '{eve:{mod_policy:"current"}}' -X DELETE -H Content-Type:application/json https://myurl.com/eve/eve_id?token=my_aut_token\&apikey=myapi_key.`

I checked with **POST & PATCH**. It takes the `JSON` as a correct form.

My RestKit Code Sample:

```
RKObjectMapping *requestMapping = [RKObjectMapping requestMapping];

[requestMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{ @"modPolicy" : @"mod_policy"}];

RKRequestDescriptor *requestDescriptor = [RKRequestDescriptor requestDescriptorWithMapping:requestMapping  objectClass:[Event class]   rootKeyPath:@"eve"];

RKObjectMapping *responseMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Events class]];

[responseMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
                                                      @"data" : @"data",
                                                      @"status":@"status"
                                                      }];

RKResponseDescriptor *responseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:responseMapping   pathPattern:nil   keyPath:@""  statusCodes:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:200]];

[objectManager addRequestDescriptor:requestDescriptor];
[objectManager addResponseDescriptor:responseDescriptor];

NSString * urlPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/eve/%@?token=%@&apikey=%@",eventID,loginToken,apiKey];

[objectManager deleteObject:hubEve path:urlPath parameters:nil success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *result)
 {
     DLog(@" response code is %d",operation.HTTPRequestOperation.response.statusCode);
     Events * _event = [result firstObject];
     DLog(@"status %@",_event.status);
     
     if([_eventt.status isEqualToString:@"success"])
     {
        DLog("Move Next"); 
        
     }
 } failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
     DLog("error %@",error);
 }];
```

Some log details, if I send As DeleteObject in request:

> `request.body=(null)  //Restkit Log`

Or if I send as **post Object/Patch Object**

> `request.body={"eve":{"mod_policy":"all"}}   //Restkit Log`

Answer (score 2):

Request mapping is explicitly not performed for `DELETE` requests. RestKit expects that when deleting you will be using the system to add parameters into the URL. You will need to plan some other method by which to delete. This could be using the RestKit mapping operation to create the payload data and then using the methods to create the URL request and setting the body data explicitly.

Comment: Do you found this somewhere in the documentation?

Answer (score 0):

RESTKit does not support DELETE request with request.body parameter
natively because HTTP 1.1 doesn't support DELETE request with
request.body. There is a work around to set request.body explicitly but
its complex.

The request works well with cURL but not with HTTP, maybe because cURL
does not send DELETE request with request.body as DELETE but upgrades it
to PUT, we are not sure though.

Comment: HTTP 1.1 doesn't say it is not supported. Here is some more information: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/299628/is-an-entity-body-allowed-for-an-http-delete-request